# DictReader error: expected string or Unicode object, list found

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I am trying to read a google sheet document with permissions like this:

```
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('Accept-Charset', 'utf-8')]
    response = opener.open(
       "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ID/export?format=csv"
    )
    csv_records = unicodecsv.reader(response, encoding='utf-8')
    translations = csv.DictReader(csv_records) 
    for row in translations:
       print row["age"]
```

however, I get an error :  `expected string or Unicode object, list found` probably for the fieldnames.

What's wrong?

**Stack trace**:

```
  File "/Users/me/projects/ad_copy.py", line 68, in create_copies
    for row in translations
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 107, in next
    self.fieldnames
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 90, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = self.reader.next()
TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, list found
```

**Print**

```
print translations
print csv_records
<csv.DictReader instance at 0x11163fa28>
<unicodecsv.py2.UnicodeReader object at 0x11160da50>
```

Comment: Post the stack trace please

Comment: Have yout tried to print some debug information, like translations or data?

Comment: Just posted the stack trace

Comment: @rocksteady added print of the objects translations and csv_records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, unicodecsv returns a list, in your case `csv_records`.

This is taken from the [github README](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv):

```
>>> import unicodecsv as csv
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> f = BytesIO()
>>> w = csv.writer(f, encoding='utf-8')
>>> _ = w.writerow((u'é', u'ñ'))
>>> _ = f.seek(0)
>>> r = csv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8')
>>> next(r) == [u'é', u'ñ']
True
```

See the comparison at the end.

You put this returned list into a `csv.DictReader()`, which is not necessary, since the result already is within `csv_records`.

Print out this variable, see what is inside.