# How to read csv file in html?

Tags: python, html, django, csv

I have a code and the thing I am not understanding is why a function of some_view in *views.py* is not fetching files from CSV. Is there something wrong? There is also html file by the name of *index.html*. I want it to  fetch the first column of CSV and make a loop in html so that I don't have to repeat it every time.

views.py

```
def some_view(request):
    reader = csv.DictReader(open('file.csv','r'))
    csv_output = []
    data = csv.reader(reader)
    for row in data:
        csv_output.append(row)
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={'csv_content': csv_output})
```

*index.html*

```
{% for content in csv_content %}
    <div class="row">
        {% for k in content.items %}
        <div class="column">
        <p> value is {{v}} </p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
   </div>
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Is there anyone to answer me?

Comment: Could be an encode issue in csv file. try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633795/dictreader-error-expected-string-or-unicode-object-list-found

Comment: That didn't answer my question.

Comment: Why do you use both `csv.reader` and `csv.DictReader`? If you just use one of them, it should work. Also, to read table, using `pandas.read_html()` coulb be easier